# How can i make repetitve loop in python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I needed help with some python programming.
I want some code that prints 1 to 10. Each time it starts from 1 to 10.
Something like this:

```
1  
12  
123  
1234  
12345  
123456  
1234567  
12345678  
123456789  
12345678910
```

Here's the code I have:

```
num = []
for num in range(0,11):
    numb.append(num)
    for word in numb:
        print(numb)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need two loops - one nested within another. One to print the rows and another to print the numbers within the rows. The range of the first loop is pretty straight forward, but the range of the nested loop will depend on the parent loop.

For Python 3.x:

```
for i in range(1,11):
    for j in range(1, i+1):
        print(j, end="")
    print()
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Only one loop needs to be explicit: `for i in range(1, 10+1):print(*range(1, i+1), sep='')`

Comment: Tiny bit shorter than previous suggestion: `for i in range(10):print(*range(1, i+2), sep='')`

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this: You'll have an outer loop, and an inner loop. The outer loop is going to represent doing something for X number of lines. The inner loop is going to represent what happens Y times per line.

So, in your example, X will be 10. Y is a bit more tricky - It actually depends on which step you're on while counting from 0 to X-1. When you do something like:

```
for i in range(5):
```

The variable i represents which step you're on. So you can use that as your bound for the inner loop.

I'm not going to post a full code solution here because this looks like a homework question, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: @V3n0mSyk3 Just FYI (and I mean this in the kindest way possible) StackOverflow is not a place to ask for code to be written for you. That's the vibe your question gives off and it's the source of the downvotes. Using Kuhnerdm's advice try it yourself and if you have any issues we'd be happy to help -- after you've given it a shot :)